# sorted() not sorting list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list consisting of sublists, and I want to find the second highest number from the sublist, so I used a sorting function. However, the list is still not sorted.

```
all_bids = [zip(*each_entry)[4]]
allbids = sorted(all_bids)
print(allbids)
```

Output:

```
all_bids = [('10.00', '7.50', '12.50', '20.00')]
alibis = [('10.00', '7.50', '12.50', '20.00')]
```

Expected Output:

```
[('7.50', '10.00', '12.50', '20.00')]
```

Comment: You have a tuple inside a list. Get rid of the list: `all_bids = zip(*each_entry)[4]`.

Comment: It *did* sort the list.  Your list has only one element, a tuple of four elements.

Comment: To start with, your list contains *a single tuple*, so there's nothing to sort. Second, your tuple contains *strings* not numbers. So even assuming you wanted to sort the tuple, they will sort lexicographically

Comment: haha spelling error. thank you all for suggestion, i converted tuple to list and now am able to sort

Comment: user6662097: In that case, please delete your question so folks don't waste time on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're working on, but I can figure out that the `all_bids` was sorted accordingly (that's smallest item first). To get the reverse you could do

```
sorted(*each_entry()[4], reverse=True)
```

and lastly to solve your problem, you have to create a sorting function, and use the `key` parameter.

**Edit**
I tried your code and this gave me your desired output.

```
x = sorted(('10.00', '7.50', '12.50', '20.00'), key=float)
    print(x)
```